# how to call new widgets in sidebar in custom theme?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, code

I am developing a theme in which I want to call available widgets *ex. Calendar* and the installed plugin, I have put it in the sidebar from widget panel but can't see in frontend.

Sidebar.php Code->

```
<div id="sidebar">

<h2>News & Announcements</h2>

<ul class="sidebar_list">



<?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>
You can color this theme as you wish, by its powerful theme options panel. It has great      documentation.<br /><br /><br />

<?php if (is_page(array('home', 'about-us', 'academics', 'admission', 'activities',  'hall-of-fame', 'alumni', 'photo-gallery', 'news' ))) ?>
<?php $menu=wp_nav_menu('menu=sidebar_menu'); ?>
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'Sidebar' )) : ?>
<?php //If dynamic sidebar not found show the default widgets  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>

</div>
```

functions.php Code->

```
<?php

if(function_exists('register_sidebar'))
{
// Sidebar Widget
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Left-Sidebar',
'before_widget'=>'<li>',
'after_widget'=>'</li>',
'before_title'=>'<h3>',
'after_title'=>'</h3>'
));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will put a basic code to create new widget. In WordPress its call `register_sidebar;` In your code, you have not put ID. `Id=>your-widget-id`

Put this code into your functions.php

```
function my_widget(){
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Front Sidebar', 'yourtheme' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => __( 'This is description', 'yourtheme' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside>',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widget' );
```

then put this code in your index.php or sidebar.php (wherever you want)

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : //check the sidebar if used.
dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );  // show the sidebar.
endif;
```

Remember to put the ID.

More http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: I have to paste this as it is:  Id=>your-widget-id
or specify the id number also??

Comment: No. It just for example. Try my code like i said above.